# open .db-file from python script returns empty file

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

I want to open a .db-file from python to inspect it. I can open it from a terminal,

```
    % sqlite3 scrapy_quotes.db
    sqlite> .tables
    author     quote      quote_tag  tag      
    sqlite> select * from quote limit 3
    ...
```

but from a python-script it only shows an empty file,

```
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine, inspect
    engine = create_engine('sqlite:///scrapy_quotes.db')
    insp = inspect(engine)
    print(insp.get_table_names())
    []
```

while this script does work for another .db-file.

```
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine, inspect
    engine = create_engine('sqlite:///chinook.db')
    insp = inspect(engine)
    print(insp.get_table_names())
    ['albums', 'artists', 'customers', 'employees', 'genres',                 
    'invoice_items', 'invoices', 'media_types', 
    'playlist_track', 'playlists', 'sqlite_sequence', 
    'sqlite_stat1', 'tracks']
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your error, are you sure the paths are right ?

```py
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect("/tmp/test.db")
con.execute("CREATE TABLE test (id INT)")
con.commit()
con.close()
```

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, inspect

engine = create_engine("sqlite:////tmp/test.db")
inspect(engine).get_table_names()  # gives ['test']
```

```
% sqlite3 /tmp/test.db
SQLite version 3.32.3 2020-06-18 14:16:19
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> .tables
test
sqlite> CREATE TABLE reverse (id INT);
```

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, inspect

engine = create_engine("sqlite:////tmp/test.db")
inspect(engine).get_table_names()  # gives ['reverse', 'test']
```

Comment: The OP is only using three slashes, so it's a relative path.

Comment: wrong paths indeed

Comment: @snakecharmerb relpath also works, I just didn't want to pollute the directory I was in.